# Modules work in play framework 2.0?

Tags: module, playframework-2.0, fb-graph

I still a noob in play framework and still trying to adapt to the environment. A bug appears when i was trying to install the fbgraph in play framework 2.0, so i "solved" it by decreasing my play framework version to play framework 1.2. After doing this, the command `play install any_module_name` worked for any module! Incredible!...

So my question is "does modules work in play framework 2.0" if yes how can i install them?

I hope some one answer this! I "think" still better to work with 2.0 ...

best regards

Comment: It's my understanding that none of the plugins for v1.x work on v2.x, but I'm not a plugin writer, so I can't say for sure.  They are trying to create a canonical repository of modules [here](http://www.playmodules.net/), but I don't see one for fbgraph.

Comment: Thanks anyway, you still give me a nice link for modules.